# Giving a UIImageView a "turning" animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, animation, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` and I would like it to have a turning movement, like turning around something. I don't want to use `UIView` animation, but something else. How can I do this please?

Comment: UIView block based animation would be really easy.  Any reason why not?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(...);
[imageView setTransform:rotation];
```

and change the rotation amount often enough for it to be smooth, but using Core Animation (like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199608/core-animation-rotating-a-layer-around-arbitrary-point)) would be better and more optimized.

Comment: No I don't wanna use a UIView animation because in my program I CAN'T USE it so that 's why I'm finding another way to do it

Comment: yes ut my programm is a a window app so I can't use open GL code on it and I don't really know how to code with open GL :/

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a window app, do you mean console? you want to render stuff offscreen? in any case if you want a rotating UIImageView, without using UIView animations, Core Animation, Core Graphics, or open GL, your options are getting limited.